# divisions with images clinging into each other

Tags: css, angularjs, user-interface, ui-design

I am trying to create a product detail page with the thumbnails of the product. But I am unable to figure out why my div s cling into each other.
example -
[image: one of the products]
[image: 2nd product spoils the allignment]

I am new to UI designing. Can someone please look into and suggest me accordingly. Or how should i proceed with designing the product detail page?

Adding my divs-
**TemplateCarousel**

```
</div>
<div id="sync2" style="height:300px;width:300px " class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="img/a.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/a.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/3.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/4.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>

</div>
```

**The consumer of the template**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 "><p >Box 1 <carousel></carousel></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 "><p>Box 2</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 "><p>Box 3</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not 100% sure what you mean by "clinging to eachother" I suggest padding or margins if you think they are too close. But use a bootstrap framework to make everything in ui design easier.

Comment: @ Joe Lloyd by that I mean they are getting into each other. I have also added the <div>s up there. Please suggest

Comment: oh i see, add another class and make it `display: block` or `display: inline-block` play around with it until you get the desired result. add padding and margins too. this is more a css problem than anything else.